# WEBAPI - passing large base 64 string in request is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i created a web api service that has an upload document functionality, it works when my document is less than 4MB. but when i am passing a base 64 string that is worth >4MB  document, the request body is null/empy.

this is what my model looks like:

```
public class UploadReq {
  public List<FileDetails>  FD {get;set;}
}

Public class FileDetails {
  public string FileName {get;set;}
   public byte[] Content {get;set;}
}
```

my controller looks like this

```
[HttPost]
[Route('api/uploaddoc')]
public Response Upload([FromBody]UploadReq req){
   //when breakpoint hits here, req.FileDetails has a length of 0, it is empty.
}
```

in my web config i have already added a maxRequestLength="5000000" in the system.web/httpruntime. aside from that i have also added in the web.config system.webserver/requestfiltering/requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" .

i am not sure if this is only a configuration issue or i need to change somethin in my code.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see actual response from server (the return status).  Are you getting 200 OK with no data?  The server may be set to a limit and not return anything.

Comment: i am only testing this locally first with postman.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  A sniffer will still work and you local machine may have limits set for download size.

Comment: do you find your answer? i have the same problem.